# The specified module 'MSOnline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-office-365, .net, entra-id

For one of my applications I have a Windows service (on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64) which role is to execute many jobs on differents schedules and triggers. One of them is to reset a user password on Office 365. The server on which the service runs has the Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant and the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell installed (MSOnline version 1.1.166.0).

From PowerShell I can successfuly call the following with my user.

```
$> $cred = Get-Credential
$> Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
```

If I run PowerShell as the account my service is started with it also runs fine. Running the reset password function from the Windows service fail with the following message :

```
The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Adding  a debug flag to the module import in the code allowed us to drag down the problem to the import-module MSOnline command. We got the error :

```
The specified module 'MSOnline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

We already tried to remove and reinstall in x64 version the two tools  (Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant and the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell). System variable "PATH" is correct with :
    %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\

Folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules has the MSOL module subfolders MSOnline and MSOnlineExtended

Copying the two folders in C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules as reported as solution in many other topics fails here with the following error :

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
```

The code used for the Windows service has been run and tested successfuly as a separate tool on the same server and the code has also been run flawlessly on a developer machine.

These investigations leads us to think there is some kind of issue with the service itself but can't figure out what/why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the issue. Changing the target platform build parameter to "Prefer 32-bits" in the project properties solved the issue.